# JavaScript Notification API requireInteraction

Tags: javascript, notifications, cross-browser

Trying to understand how this feature works.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification/requireInteraction) article says:

> The requireInteraction read-only property of the Notification
>   interface returns a Boolean indicating that a notification should
>   remain active until the user clicks or dismisses it, rather than
>   closing automatically.

My test page has this js script:

```
new Notification("Header text", {
    icon: '/images/someImage.png',
    body: 'Notification body text!',
    requireInteraction : true
});
```

Tested in different browsers. Windows 10.

- Chrome (56.0.2924.87) - support, no auto-close
- Firefox (53.0a2 dev) - ignores this flag, auto-close after 20 seconds
- Edge (38.14393.0.0) - ignores this flag, auto-close after about 6 seconds, uses windows notifications, and info stay in notification panel
- Opera (43.0.2442.1144) - ignores this flag, auto-close after about 6
  seconds, uses windows notifications, info not stay in notification
  panel
- Yandex browser (17.3.0.1849) support, no auto-close (think it
  uses chrome inside)

Checked it on android device - notifications stay in notification panel while you don't close them manually.

Some remark about firefox. [Here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=862395) is a bug info about this. It has status:

> RESOLVED FIXED in Firefox 52

Checked in both 52 and 53 versions. Results are above. Is this a bug?

And main question: is i am doing it (creating notifications) wrong? Or this is impossible to achieve cross-browser not auto-closing notifications using Notification API?

Comment: Regarding firefox. It seems that for this flag to work dom.webnotifications.requireinteraction.enabled must be set to true in about:config. However, it still does not work for me in FF 53